# How to reference a Profile111 PCL from a netstandard2.0 assembly?

Tags: portable-class-library, .net-standard-2.0

I have a profile111-pcl-assembly which should be used by a netstandard2.0 class library.

The compatibility chart [1] says that Profile111 already is compatible with netstandard1.1.
But I always get this silly warning:

> warning NU1701: Package 'Name' was restored using
>   '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework
>   '.NETStandard,Version=v2.0'. This package may not be fully compatible
>   with your project.

Why the f*ck should it **NOT** be fully compatible with my project?

I already tried using `<PackageTargetFallback>` but this did not change anything.

[1] https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/schema/target-frameworks